# How to make dynamic links crawable through google

Tags: seo, web-crawler, google-crawlers

I have question/answer website where each question has a link. 
My problem is how do I fed this link to google ? 
Should I write link in "site.xml" or "robot.xml" ? 
What is standard solution to this problem ??

Thanks
Amit Aggarwal

Answer (score 1):

Some advices:

- First make sure your website is SEO friendly and is crawl-able by search engines.
- Second make sure to publish your webpage site-map to Google.
- To do that `add your site to Google Webmaster` and submit your sitemap (XML, RSS, ATOM feed formats).

Consider using URL rewriting tool to convert your URLs from DYNAMIC to more SEO and user friendly version:
Example:

FROM:

```
example.com/product?id=100
```

TO:

```
example.com/nameproduct
```

Related information:

https://support.google.com/sites/answer/100283?hl=en

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en

Comment: I did all this. My question is, When user create a question at my site, I assign a url through which question can be fetch. Now how can I give this url to google for crawling ?