# Pages based on url queries, is google gonna index them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, seo

Hi I have a doubt about google indexing.

I usually see websites that when you look for them in google they display like this

```
Website x
home     oferts   
jobs     about-us
sign up  etc...
```

well I have an app made on Ruby on Rails, and my principal pages are based on queries so for example I have 3 principal pages in my website, and these are the urls

```
mywebsite.com/?mos_popular=true
mywebsite.com/?featured=true
mywebsite.com/?best_discounts=true
```

that's it so, as you can see I do not have separate urls or pages for each one, they are just query based.

So my question is how do I tell google to index my website like

```
mywebsite.com
Most-popular   Best-discounts
featured       sign up
```

knowing that my principal pages are not regular urls (query based), and also I want to know if that is this a SEO disadvange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned on [Google Webmaster page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en),

> Google only show sitelinks for results when we think they'll be
>   useful to the user. If the structure of your site doesn't allow our
>   algorithms to find good sitelinks, or we don't think that the
>   sitelinks for your site are relevant for the user's query, we won't
>   show them.

As suggested in their article you can try to have more internal links and make sure you use anchor text and alt text are informative and short.

Consider also to use `URL rewriting tools` so you can re-write your link from query string

FROM:

```
mywebsite.com/?mos_popular=true
mywebsite.com/?featured=true
mywebsite.com/?best_discounts=true
```

TO a more SEO and user friendly version:

```
mywebsite.com/popular
mywebsite.com/featured
mywebsite.com/bestdiscounts
```

If Google as added your URLs in their SERP but you are not happy about what they are displaying in their SERP, you can use Google Webmaster tool in order to manage your Site Link.

Comment: Ho yea I can use url rewriting gem, thank you, and also sending the sitemap is good for let google know how to index my website right?

Comment: Yes definitely site map is always good :) You can read more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497762/how-to-make-dynamic-links-crawable-through-google/28516957#28516957